# Flutter Animating listview elements is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to do a glow effect on the container. I am using streambuilder to build list items and when item price changes I want to show container glow effect. So far I have done this but the widget doesn't show the effect at all. didUpdateWidget doesn't show any update and when it does, all of the listview items animates themselves for infinite amount of time. Is there something I am missing?

```
 AnimationController _animationController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(CustomContainer oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.price != widget.price) {
      print("changed");
      _animationController.repeat(
          reverse: true, period: Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animationController,
        builder: (context, _) {
          return Container(
            height:100,
            width:double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 4 * _animationController.value,
                  color: primaryColor.withOpacity(0.7),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`AnimationController.repeat()` will start running the animation and repeat it an infinite amount of times. This is why the items are animating themselves for infinitely. You would have to use `.forward` method instead:

```
_animationController = AnimationController(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  vsync: this);

_animationController.forward(); //tell the animation to start without repeating
```

From [Flutter Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial#animationcontroller):

> AnimationController is a special Animation object that generates a new
> value whenever the hardware is ready for a new frame. By default, an
> AnimationController linearly produces the numbers from 0.0 to 1.0
> during a given duration.
>
> AnimationController derives from Animation, so it can be used
> wherever an Animation object is needed. However, the
> AnimationController has additional methods to control the animation.
> For example, you start an animation with the .forward() method. The
> generation of numbers is tied to the screen refresh, so typically 60
> numbers are generated per second. After each number is generated, each
> Animation object calls the attached Listener objects. To create a
> custom display list for each child, see [RepaintBoundary](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RepaintBoundary-class.html).

Here is the docs for `AnimationController.forward()`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController/forward.html

Comment: Actually I believe animation controller will repeat for provided period of time on _repeat. But that's not the only issue. didUpdateWidget is not firing even when data is changed. And each individual widget is not animating rather every widget animates themselves when it does.

Comment: It would be better to use Bloc state management to fire when the data changes. You can pass the animation controller to the functions and make it go forward. Calling didUpdateWidget every time a widget changes is very inefficient. It would be better to use StreamBuilders to update a specific widget in a screen instead of all at once. I personally use rxdart for bloc state management: https://medium.com/flutter-community/why-use-rxdart-and-how-we-can-use-with-bloc-pattern-in-flutter-a64ca2c7c52d

Comment: I am using rxdart based bloc for state management and still running into this problem.

Comment: Could you update your code? Also, the new keyword is now optional. You could remove them.

Comment: remove didUpdateWidget and add AnimationController.forward() when every time you want to update your widget. Place AnimationController.forward() below _subject.add() .

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense at all. I want to animate one item at a time not all. Moving _animationController which is a UI component to bloc doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are passing the animation controller to bloc to tell it to start animating. The whole point of bloc is to separate the ui code from the backend code and update only specific widget that needs to get updated. You would only call AnimationController.forward() after you are finished updating a certain item you want. Let's say you want to update a Text widget and not your Container(). With bloc, you have a function that updates the text using the setText function. So inside that function, place AnimationController.forward() after calling myTextStream.add("new text")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224241/discussion-between-zero-live-and-uni).